# Bootstrap collapsed navbar extends horizontally after changing the breakpoint

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Im using a bootstrap navigation bar as follows:

```
<div id="custom-nav" class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
    <div  class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>                        
            </button>
            <a  href="#"><img style="margin-top:5px" src="images/logo.png" /></a>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li><a class="active" href="#">ANASAYFA</a></li>
                <li><a href="page1.html">KURUMSAL</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">UYGULAMALAR</a></li> 
                <li><a href="#">ÇÖZÜMLER</a></li> 
                <li><a href="#">ÜRÜNLER</a></li> 
                <li><a href="#">REFERANSLAR</a></li> 
                <li><a href="#">İLETİŞİM</a></li> 
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I had to change the collapsing breakpoint of my navbar to 900px using the following code. It was 768px by default.

```
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 899px) {
    .navbar-collapse.collapse {
        display: none !important;
    }
    .navbar-collapse.collapse.in {
        display: block !important;  
    }
    .navbar-header .collapse, .navbar-toggle {
        display:block !important;
    }
    .navbar-header {
        float: none;
    }
}
```

Now between 900px and 768px when i extend the collapsed navbar, it shows the items horizontally.

How can i make it so it will show the items vertically just like below 768px ?

Comment: you are missing a curly brace at the end of your css

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had to override some more Bootstrap functionality

I added some more changes to make it look better and not only make them align vertically.:

```
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 899px) {
        .navbar-collapse.collapse {
            display: none !important;
        }

        .navbar-collapse.collapse.in {
            display: block !important;
        }

        .navbar-header .collapse, .navbar-toggle {
            display: block !important;
        }

        .navbar-header {
            float: none;
        }

        /*

            The changes start from here:

        */

        .navbar-right {
            float: none !important;
        }

        .navbar-nav > li {
            float: none;
        }

        .navbar-nav > li > a {
            padding-top: 10px;
            padding-bottom: 10px;
        }

        .navbar-collapse {
            -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, .1);
            box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, .1);
        }

        .container-fluid > .navbar-collapse {
            margin-right: -15px;
            margin-left: -15px;
        }

        .container-fluid > .navbar-header {
            margin-right: -15px;
            margin-left: -15px;
        }
    }
```

Comment: You're an angel. Thanks so much :) too bad i dont have enough rep to +rep you :(